# Why detections count is not equal to unique truth count in YOLOv4 test result report?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, model-evaluation, object-detection

I trained model using YOLOv4 on GPU, CUDNN and openCV (python) with [AlexeyAB\Darknet](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet) with multi-label on windows environment. These labels are *25 classes* (from 0 to 24). Then I test the model and I got this report as shown [image: here].

I confused about the numbers that colored in yellow, blue and red that appear in the report (detection_count , unique_truth_count,TP, FP,and FN). Which composed the four values of  comfusion matrix as to validate the performance of the model.

Why there is difference gab between number of detection_count and unique_truth_count?

In the other words:
FN = *unique_truth_count - TP*, SO *(32,801 - 31,295)* = 1,506

But:
*detection_count* isn't equals (**TP + FP + FN**)  which include all detection(40,724 is not equals to (31,295 + 1,599 + 1,506))